# Program that determines college admissions using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

First, I just want to say I know this is a lot, but all I really want is for someone to look over the code I've written and also help clarify what exactly I'm supposed to do. Thank you!

Hi,
So I'm relatively new to coding and I'm trying to write a program that uses multiple functions to determine if a student gets accepted, rejected, or waitlisted. I've attempted writing code for each part, but I'm unsure if I'm doing it the way I'm supposed to or if there is a better way of writing it. If someone could look over my codes and let me know or give me any advice, that would be greatly appreciated. Also, could tell me if I'm doing recursion correctly? Thanks!

The criteria for admission are based on the scores on the three parts of the SAT, and rank in the high school graduating class; the exact criteria are given below.  These rules are applied in the priority order shown here (1, 2, 3, etc).

1. If the input data is invalid (SAT less than 200 or greater than 800, or a class rank that is not a positive integer) the they are rejected
2. If any test score is 800, the they are accepted
3. If any test score is below 300, the they are rejected
4. If the average test score is greater than 650 and the class rank less than or equal to 25, they are accepted.
5. If two or more of the test scores are less than 400 or the class rank is greater than or equal to 75, they are rejected.
6. In any other instance, the applicant is placed on a waiting-list

Da program to replace the spreadsheet (with several functions) to determine if a student will be accepted, rejected or wait-listed. Your solution MUST contain the following functions:

Part 1: A function called admissionStatus(sat_math,sat_reading,sat_writing,class_rank) that accepts 4 parameters (as shown) and returns a string "Accept", "Reject", or "Waitlist"

Part 2: A function called isvalid(sat_math,sat_reading,sat_writing,class_rank) that returns True or False, depending on whether the input data are valid. If all of the data is valid, it returns True, otherwise it returns False.

Part 3: A main function that prompts the user for pertinent data (applicant name, math sat score, reading sat score, writing sat score, and class rank. It also calls admissionStatus() passing the appropriate parameters.

Part 4: Any other helper functions that you think appropriate (Implement some of the computations within admission status as separate functions that can be called from admission status.  For instance, you might want to write a function for rule 2 above).

Design test data to cover as many possibilities as you can.  You should have at least one set of test data for each of the seven criteria above; probably more, since there are several different ways, for instance, that the input data can be invalid.

Here's what I've done:

Part 1:

```
import math
sat_math = raw_input ("Input your SAT math score")
sat_reading = raw_input ("Input your SAT reading score")
sat_writing = raw_input ("Input your SAT writing score"
class_rank = int(raw_input ("Input your class rank"))
a = [sat_math, sat_reading, sat_writing]
if sat_math or sat_reading or sat_writing > 800:
    return "Rejected"
 if sat_math or sat_reading or sat_writing < 200:
     return "Rejected"
if sat_math or sat_reading or sat_writing == 800:
    return "Accepted"
elif sat_math or sat_reading or sat_writing <= 300:
    return "Rejected"
elif (sum(a)/len(a) > 650) and class_rank <= 25:
    return "Accepted"
elif sat_math + sat_reading < 400:
    return "Rejected"
elif sat_math + sat_writing < 400:
    return "Rejected"
elif sat_reading + sat_writing < 400:
    return "Rejected"
elif class_rank >= 75:
    return "Rejected"
else:
    Return "Waitlisted"
```

Part 2 (this is the part I'm most confused about):

```
def isvalid(sat_math,sat_reading,sat_writing,class_rank):
sat_math = raw_input ("Input your SAT math score")
sat_reading = raw_input ("Input your SAT reading score")
sat_writing = raw_input ("Input your SAT writing score")
class_rank = int(raw_input ("Input your class rank"))
while True:
    sat_math or sat_reading or sat_reading >= 200
    sat_math or sat_reading or sat_reading <= 800
    class_rank == int()
else:
    break
```

Part 3: I don't see the difference between this one and the first one (other than asking for a name), so if someone could explain that to me that would be great.

Part 4: I'm not exactly sure what this one means. Does it mean writing a separate function for each step?

Finally, when it says "test data," am I supposed to write up different scenarios with different SAT scores each time and test them?

Like I said earlier- I know this is a lot, but all I really want is for someone to look over the code I've written and also help clarify what exactly I'm supposed to do. Thank you!

Comment: Using python2.7 btw!

Comment: You will need to pare this down to a single, specific, answerable question. As it is, I'd say that what you need is a tutor.

Comment: You've been downvoted because stackoverflow is not a code review service; it exists to answer directed, specific questions. Please review [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try again.

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes the person needs to help themselves first by reading a book on the language, the on-line documentation, or asking someone they know who can help them. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question, fix the obvious mistakes, and get it re-opened.

Comment: For one thing, this code doesn't run at all, and you don't seem to realize it.  I strongly recommend that you work with incremental programming: write a few lines, make sure they work, and continue with that process, one tiny step at a time.  Designing in large chunks is fine, but part of your problem is that you're trying to express that in *code*, and you're not yet ready for that much at once.

Comment: A tutor would be ideal if I could afford one. I'm desperate and looking for a little help- can you blame me after staying up till 4AM working on comsci? I figured some experts would at least show some compassion and provide some help. I'm not trying to steal answers, I genuinely want to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't review your full code, and would suggest you to ask more specific questions as others also suggested. I have still tried to answer some of your questions:

Your part 1 should be a function (def admissionStatus()...). For Part 3 and 4, it seems you are being asked to modularize your code. So, in part 3, create a function to read all the user inputs, and from this function, call the function admissionStatus() that you created in part 1 to check admission status. In part 4, see if you can modularize further. The question specifically gives hints - "For instance, you might want to write a function for rule 2 above". This program seems too simple to require many functions, but I guess you are trying to learn how to program, so for the purpose of learning, maybe you can create the functions.

Comment: Is part 1 not already a function? Also, what do you mean by modularize?

Comment: In part 1, create a function like you did for part 2 (def function_name (parameters)). By modularize, I meant split the code up into multiple functions where you can rather than writing all the logic in one function/block. Your task has a hint; it says "For instance, you might want to write a function for rule 2 above". By the way, your code has errors - fix them, or it won't work.